# how does "click: test()" work in KO?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

my view model

```
function Test() {}
Test.prototype.test = function() { alert('hi'); }
```

my view

```
<button data-bind="click: test()">Click me</button>
```

code that runs it

```
var test = new Test();
ko.applyBindings(test);
```

fiddle:
   https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/

question:

- can anyone explain what is going on here, the `test()` is a call expression which is supposed to be evaluated to `undefined` at binding (which you can see when the alert is displayed the first time), so `click: test()` is as good as `click: undefined`, if so how come i see the alert when i click the button?
- can anyone share a link to the official Knockout documentation that explains it?

**UPDATE:**

to illustrate it better, if we add another binding `text: test()` we see that the text on the button disappears at binding (as expected, because tests returns undefined), if so, what is the difference between evaluating `click` and `text`?

```
<button data-bind="click: test(), text: test()">
Click me
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/3/

**UPDATE:**

crossposted at knockout: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2246

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand.
You are binding the viewmodel test to the document and then tell the button to bind with the function 'test' inside that viewmodel. Because you used data-bind="click: test()" it is executed on load. the correct binding would be data-bind="click: test"

Comment: the button works when you click it, this is what i don't understand, did you read the question?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to work then? This is normal behavior if you ask me ...

Comment: I am no expert in knockoutJS but from the fiddle what I understood is that. When `ko.applyBindings(test);` is called it binds the scope of `Test` and evaluates all `data-bind` property in HTML element. Hence, you see what happens is it evaluates `click: test()` thus an alert is fired on page load.

What I observerd is If you use  `click: test`  in `data-bind` property it doesnot fire the alert on page load.

Thus, what I can conclude is that `ko.applyBindings(test);` binds the scope provide in the parameter to all the elements with the parameter `data-bind` in it.

Comment: in my opinion it's not supposed to work because `test()` returns `undefined` and this `undefined` is supposed to be used as a handler for the `click`

Comment: No, How will that be undefined. your `data-bind` attribute in the HTML tag is not evaluated by Browser on rendering the page. It is evaluated when you are calling   `ko.applyBindings(test);` as you are passing `test` as a parameter to `appliBindings` it knows all the prototype of `Test` and it has no problem evaluating   ` data-bind="click: test()"`. and test is not undefined.

Comment: @NadirLaskar yes, after `ko.applyBindings(test);` do `alert(test.test())` and see for yourself, it shows `undefined`, so back to my point `test()` gets you `undefined`, which is not a function to be called: https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/1/

Comment: @AlekseyBykov check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/2/

Comment: what you are alerting is undefined `alert(test.test());` because `test.test()` returns undefined.

Comment: Your `alert(test.test());` is simply calling `function() { alert('hi'); }` inside an alert like `alert(function() { alert('hi'); });` which will alert two times one inside the function `function() { alert('hi'); }` and another with the return value of the function which is `undefined` as you are not returning anything from `function() { alert('hi'); }`

Comment: right, this is exactly my point when you call `test()` you get `undefined`, `undefined` is supposed to be used as a handler for the `click` binding, if so, it is supposed to be an exception when you click the button because you cannot make calls to `undefined`

Comment: No, Knockout doesn't work this way. From the behavior we can see it is not binding the result of any function call to the click it is binding the function itself. They are not evaluating the function `test()` before binding the response rather they are adding the test function itself.

Comment: @NadirLaskar i understand that somehow it works, it's not even the question, the question is why it works like that and where in the official documentation it is explained

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/4/

Comment: @AlekseyBykov if you return a function from the `test()` instead of undefined it added both `test` and returned function to the click handler.

Comment: @NadirLaskar nice, do you have a link to an official knowckout documentation where this behavior is explained?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov No, They don't have this explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, the binding `click: test()` gets transformed into `click: function() { return test() }`. The "value-accessor" function is then passed to the binding handler. Examining the [code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L23) for the `event` binding (which `click` uses), we can see that `valueAccessor` is called each time the event happens. The result of the value-accessor is then used by the binding.

Here's why you shouldn't use `click: test()`:

1. The function will be called [initially](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L18), when bindings are first applied. You likely would never want that.
2. The default `click` behavior doesn't get canceled like it's supposed to if you set the binding correctly. See https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/6/

Further information:

As described in the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html), bindings can contain JavaScript expressions such as `text: price() > 50 ? 'expensive' : 'cheap'`. This is true of any binding. The expression will be re-evaluated whenever the binding is updated. For events, the expression is evaluated initially and then whenever the event occurs. The `event` binding expects the expression to return a function, but it [silently ignores a falsy return value](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L24) (such as `undefined`).

If you really want to bind an event to an expression to run, check out the [`on.*` bindings](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/#expression-based-event-handling) from http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/

Comment: how is the evaluation of `click: test` different from `click: test()`? if we assume (according to what you said) that they both get wrapped we will get `click: function() { return test() }` and `click: function() { return test; }` respectively, which have completely different semantics, what puzzles me is that both `click: test()` and `click: test` work pretty much the same way while seemingly they mean completely different things

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js

Comment: I just did, it's still a mystery what comes in `valueAccessor` and how that value is acquired

Comment: I've added some more description to my answer.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, now it makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

The "click" binding accepts function that will be called on click.

```
data-bind="click: test()"
```

evaluates "click()" function and passes returned result to the click binding handler.

```js
var model = {
  testFunc: function(model) {
    alert(model.text())
  },
  text: ko.observable("some text")
}

ko.applyBindings(model);

setTimeout(function() { model.text("another text"); }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: testFunc, text: text">
Click me
</button>
```

[The "click" binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html):

#### Update 1.

I'm sorry for quoting documentation here, but it clearly says that

> Main parameter
>
> The function you want to bind to the element’s click event.

And there is no matter - how this function will be obtained: evaluated from inline string, passed by reference or returned as a result of inline-evaluated function or another function, or value of the observable object.

#### Update 2.

KnockoutJS wraps your expression in order to evaluate it, or reevaluate in case of it's value is an observable. And that's why your function is called on click in spite of returns nothing. After evaluating binding expression it will be transformed in to this code:

```
(function($context,$element
/*``*/) {
with($context){with($data||{}){return{'click':function(){return test() }}}}
})
```

You can check it, if you add "debugger" as first line of the "test" function. I've not found this in the KnockoutJS documentation. It's a bit confusing, but easily can be debugged.

Comment: you didn't answer the question: why it works like this and where it is explained, the link to the `click` binding doesn't explain it

Comment: there is no function passed in my example, there is a result of a **function call** that is passed to the binding, in other words `test` is a function `test()` is a function call, there is nothing in the documentation that says you can use a function call to bind to the `click`, hence the question

Comment: Result of `test()` is undefined. This mean nothing passed to the binding, and nothing to execute.

Comment: exactly, this is what puzzles me, when the expression is evaluated we get undefined, but yet somehow it works, looks like an undocumented (as far as i can tell) weird feature of KO

Comment: According to the http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html - "The binding value can be a single value, variable, or literal or almost any valid JavaScript expression."

Comment: yes, exactly, `test()` in `click: test()` is a valid javascript expression, the result of that expression is undefined, as far as i understand at binding the expression is supposed to be evaluated, and the result of the evaluation used as a handler for the click event, well the result is obviously `undefined`, which is not a valid event handler, and cannot be used, yet the click works, so there must be some special case logic in evaluator or something which i am struggling to find out

Comment: i saw your last update, would you mind to explain what happens here: https://jsfiddle.net/5g4cfg7u/4/

Comment: "And that's why your function is called on click in spite of returns nothing." it doesn't explain it, if like you said every expression is wrapped then how would `click:test` (function reference, not a function call) work: `(function($context,$element) {
with($context){with($data||{}){return{'click':function(){return test; }}}}
})`?

Comment: I've not told KnockoutJS wraps every expression.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov what do you want to achive? What problem are you solving? Probably this can help to answer your question...

Comment: i am a team lead who is in charge of the code quality, my problem is that in our team some people use `click: test()` instead of `click:test` which i think is wrong (despite it works) so i need to find a strong evidence that `click: test()` is wrong or find best practices as to how and when it should be used, not until then can we say that we know what we are doing

Comment: In this case it's obvious for me: `click: test()` causes extra and absolutely unnecessary call of the `test` function during binding processing. If you have many such a bindings this can impact rendering performance.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `click: test` works as it's expecting a function to call (which, once bound to your viewmodel, it dutifully does, showing the alert).

Calling `text: test()` returns `undefined` as there's no return value coming from that function.